# Serving php files from an aliased directory in Apache HTTPd

Tags: php, apache

I have the following apache config:

```
 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.key

    Alias /login/ /var/www/html/saml_provider/www/

    <LocationMatch "^(.*\.php)$">
         ProxyPass fcgi://presentation-php-fpm:9000/var/www/public
    </LocationMatch>

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

hitting www.example.com/hello.php works fine as the LocationMatch block picks up this is a php file and sends it on to the php-fpm engine using proxy-pass.

However, hitting www.example.com/login/hi.php does not work, giving a php "file not found" error. This makes sense, because I guess that it is trying to find the file in /var/www/public but it is actually in /var/www/html/saml_provider/www/.

How can I fix this so that php also serves any .php file on the alias such that:

www.example.com/login/hi.php  --- served by php from ----> /var/www/html/saml_provider/www/hi.php

Comment: you'd probably need two locationmatches. one for the aliased dir, and one for "everything else". fcgi won't know about the alias, since that's an "in apache only" thing. another option might be to use a symlink instead of the alias, but apache by default doesn't allow symlinks which point outside the document root for security reasons.

Comment: Try `Alias /login /var/www/html/saml_provider/www/`

Comment: @RiggsFolly ...already got that ;)

Comment: **NOTE:** You have `/login/` I have `/login` it makes a difference